# Hibernate pool does not refresh in case of database restart in case of connection leak

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, c3p0

I  am using hibernate with c3p0 connection pool   and using PostgreSQL database and configured 100 max Connection  in connection pool

**Scenario :**  Suposse multiple threads use DBSessioFactory to getConnection from hibernate c3p0 poll and every thread does not close the connection .

So there are Connection leak in every thread  . 
So in some time all pool become unavailable . As all pool are in Busy state as also seen from jmx(jconsole) .

**Issue :**  Now whats my issue is even if i restart postgresql , event though , busy connections showing is hibernate pool in jconsole is 100 . c3p0/hibernate does not understand that database has been restart and it should free this .

How should i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c3p0 has no way of knowing that Connections which, as far as it is concerned are valid and checked out, are no longer good because of a DB reset. Checked-out Connections belong to clients, c3p0 generally doesn't mess with them. The best thing to do is to fix your Connection leaks, so that this does not happen.

If you can't fix the leaks (just fix the leaks!), c3p0 does offer an ugly workaround, its [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) setting. You can set a timeout longer than a valid client would ever use, and c3p0 will eventually cleanup leaked Connections as this timeout is exceeded.

Comment: Yes  i know We need to fix the leak and definitely doing this . But this i am asking just in case if by mistake there are session leak then withoutcode change for some time till leak are fixed live enviorment does not effect . Thanx for your answer .

Comment: i got an workaround but it is not recommended  , to free your session in finalize So that  when gc will occurs all sessions will be returned to pool .

Comment: `finalize()` is in general a pretty unreliable backstop. i wouldn't put much hope in it, though it might be better than nothing. do think about setting `unreturnedConnectionTimeout`. among other things, it can help you [find and fix the leaks](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).